# reactjs - render tags accourding with condictionals

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue. I would like to render the `<a>` tag only in the case if it is validated in the conditional and it isn't work. Probabily I'm doing some typo.

```
return (
  if(this.state.currentPage > 1 ){ 
    <a className="prev-button">&lt;</a>
  }

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you pass after a *return* should be a valid JS **expression**.

**if** is a **statement**.

Check out this for a [difference between expression and statements](http://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html).

In order to have logical tests in an expression you can use the [&& or || operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) like:

```
return ({(this.state.currentPage > 1 ) && <a className="prev-button">&lt;</a>})
```

Comment: Thank you I was found the solution and I posted it before you did. But I'm very gratefully.

Comment: Yeah :) I saw that while typing the answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It is the right way to type the code:

```
{(this.state.currentPage > 1 ) && 
  <a className="prev-button">&lt;</a>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside return you need to use `{}` brackets to write your JS code.

```
return(
 {
   this.state.currentPage>1 ? <a className="prev-button">&lt;</a> : ''
 }
)
```